# Parsing JSON strings into Inherited class hierarchies using Google's GSON library

Tags: java, json, inheritance, gson

I need to parse JSON strings into below class hierarchy using Google's GSON library.

```
class Expression {
    List<Component> components;
}

class Component {
}

class Operator extends Component {
    char operator;
}

class Operand extends Component {
}

class Constant extends Operand {
    float value;
}

class Variable extends Operand {
    char name;
    float value;
}
```

Is it possible to somehow represent "Expression" objects (as defined below) into JSON strings. I am unable to understand that how can I specify type of "Component"(Operator, Operand, Constant, etc) in the JSON string.

Is it a generic limitation of JSON representation to not be able to represent Inheritence ?
If not, can somebody please give me an example JSON string representing below class hierarchy...

Comment: Gson will handle that for you. When converting back from Json to object, you simply need to pass in a class reference. It will do the rest.

Comment: Can you please provide an example JSON string ?
I am still not sure if Gson library will be able to handle this
E.g. {"components":[{"operator":'a'}, {"name":'x', value:3.5}]}

If it does, how will it handle situations where multiple inheriting classes have same set of fields (e.g. what if both "Operator" and "Operand" classes have only a single field named "field1", in this case, of what object type will Gson library create an object ?)